# Highlight table cells with header

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need the solution about

1. When we select mouse on specific cell index `(like A5)` it will be `highlighted` with headers.
2. From that `cell(A5`) if we mouse drug on other cells it also be highlighted(like A5 to D5 all cells) with their headers(like row headers 1,2,3... & column headers A,B,....).

Have any solution?

Tried for first:

```
        $('#Mytable ').on( "click","td",function() {

        $("td").removeClass("highlighted");
        $(this).addClass("highlighted").siblings().removeClass('highlighted');
        $("th").removeClass("highlighte");
        $(this).parent().find("th").addClass("highlighte");
        var t = $('#Mytable th').eq($(this).index());
        var ad= t.text();
        $('th#'+ad).addClass("highlighte");

        } );
```

CSS:

```
   .highlighted {
     border: 2px solid #0080FF ;
    }
   .highlighte {

    background-color: #808080 ;
    }
```

Tried for Second:

```
         $(window).load(function() {
         //alert('tanim');
         var isMouseDown = false;
         $("#Mytable td")
             .mousedown(function () {
                 isMouseDown = true;
                 $(this).addClass("severalcell-highlight");
                // return false; // prevent text selection
             })
             .mouseover(function () {
                 if (isMouseDown) {
                     $(this).addClass("severalcell-highlight");
                 }
             })
             .mouseup(function () {
                 if (isMouseDown) {
                     $(this).addClass("severalcell-highlight");
                 }
             })
             .bind("selectstart", function () {
                 //return false; // prevent text selection in IE
             });

         $(document)
             .mouseup(function () {
                 isMouseDown = false;

             });
         $('#Mytable').on( "click","td",function() {

             $("td").removeClass("severalcell-highlight");
         } );
     });
```

Comment: and what you have tried?

Comment: hey, please submit your code, we will try to help from there

Comment: your flag variable `isMouseDown` is declared with `var` inside the `$(window).load` function and therefore lives only during the execution of this function. Lateron, when users trigger the event functions, the variable is out of scope. Since you are using it as a global variable you should declare it without `var`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not yet solved your header highlighting problem, but the rest works. Put the following into your `$(document).ready` function:

```
mdown=false;
var funcfalse=function(){ console.log('selsta'); }
var hover=function(ev){ if (mdown) $(this).toggleClass('hi_td'); }
var mo=function(ev){
 mdown=(ev.type=='mousedown');
 if (mdown) $(this).toggleClass('hi_td');
 console.log(mdown);}
 var $tbl = $("#table-1"),$tblHead = $("#table-1 thead tr");

$("tbody td",$tbl).on({"mousedown":mo,"mouseup":mo,"mouseenter":hover
                       "selectstart":funcfalse});
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RmAqP/3/)

Of course, this is not a lasso-selection, implying a selection box. Only those elements that you have actually visited (hovered over) with mousedown will be selected or deselected (on a return visit).

**Edit 2**

Got it now! Now you actually select a box-shaped-area and the title is also highlighted (or 'highlit' ?!?) !

The following should be in the `$(document).ready` function:

```
mdown=false; msel=[[],[]];   // msel=[[startrow,endrow],[startcol,endcolcol2]]
var funcfalse=function(){console.log('selsta');} // disable IE text selection
var getpos=function(o,i){var o=$(o); // get position of current cell               
    msel[0][i]=o.parent().index();   // set row
    msel[1][i]=o.index();            // set column
    return msel;
}
var modsel=function(o){              // utility function to get cell position of o
    var r=getpos(o,1)[0].slice(0);r.sort();
    var c=       msel[1].slice(0);c.sort();
    $trs=$('#table-1 tbody tr');
    $('td',$trs).removeClass('hi_td');
    $trs.slice(r[0],r[1]+1).each(function(){
        $('td',this).slice(c[0],c[1]+1).addClass('hi_td');})
    $("#table-1 thead tr th").removeClass('hi_th')
        .slice(c[0],c[1]+1).addClass('hi_th');
}             
var hover=function(ev){ if (mdown) modsel(this); }       // event function hover
var mo=function(ev){ mdown=(ev.type=='mousedown')?1:0;   // event function mouseuo/down
    getpos(this,1-mdown);
    if (mdown) modsel(this);
}
var $tbl = $("#table-1"),$tblHead = $("#table-1 thead tr");
$("tbody td",$tbl)
    .on({"mousedown":mo,"mouseup":mo,"mouseenter":hover,"selectstart":funcfalse});
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RmAqP/6/)

**Edit 3:** (row-headers)

A modification to include leading `<th>`s in each row is also possible. I just modified my old JSfiddle accordingly. I am not very pleased with this solution yet, as it does not recognise by itself, whether a leading `<th>` is actually present or not in each line. I changed an offset manually from

```
    $trs.slice(r[0],r[1]+1).each(function(){
    $('td',this).slice(c[0],c[1]+1).addClass('hi_td');});
```

to

```
    $trs.slice(r[0],r[1]+1).each(function(){
    $('td',this).slice(c[0]-1,c[1]).addClass('hi_td');});
```

Maybe I will find a better solution soon. However, here you can find the updated [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RmAqP/7/).

**Edit 4:** (more than 9 columns):

Sorry, I was a bit lazy when I did the first version. I determine the min and max values of row and column numbers by sorting the arrays `r` and `c`. Unfortunately I simply used *alphabetic* (default) sorting, which assumes '9' to be higher than '10'. I just changed your JSfiddle in the following lines (adding the numeric sort-callback-function `numsrt`):

```
var numsrt=function(a,b){return a-b;}
var r=getpos(o,1)[0].slice(0);r.sort(numsrt);
var c=       msel[1].slice(0);c.sort(numsrt);
```

Now it works also for large tables: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RmAqP/9/)

Comment: If we add the row header like row1,row2,row3 etc and want to highlight like the column header. Is it possible by using above?

Comment: Its probably works. But if the table has many rows and columns like: http://jsfiddle.net/RmAqP/8/ . 9th and 10th columns are not working together.

Comment: It works for large tables. If we want to create a border for the selected highlighted rows & columns and also create a dragging option to the rows & columns to increase highlighting to the rows & columns. Is it possible by using above?

Answer (score 1):

You could try following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $tbl = $("#table-1"),
    $tblHead = $("#table-1 thead tr");

   $tbl.children("tbody").find("td")
    .on("mouseover",function(){
        var cellIndex = $(this).index();           
        $(this).css("background-color","#ccc");
        $tblHead.children("th").eq(cellIndex).css("background-color","blue");
    }).on("mouseleave",function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","#fff");
        var cellIndex = $(this).index();   
        $tblHead.children("th").eq(cellIndex).css("background-color","#fff");
    });
});
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/6mGLh/1/

Comment: Thnx for this example, I always wrongly believed that `index()` returned the total index position of an element in a jQuery collection, but, as you have demonstrated, it returns the position within its parent DOM structure.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the table layout maybe I can point you to the following tools/methods:

1. find out, which column (Nr `colnr`) you are in by counting the `prevAll()` elements of the current `td` in that `tr` (`this` is the current `td`): `colnr=$(this).parent().prevAll().length`
2. get the title from the `th` of the same column by filtering it with `$('table#name tr:eq(0) th:eq('+colnr+')')`
3. (just read that you want highlighting of the header) then highlight the appropriate title th as selected under 2 ...

just look at maverickosama's solution which I edited a little bit (combining the mouseenter and mouseleave events in one function), see here: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mGLh/2/)

For the complete solution see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17989019/2610061)!

Comment: see below (->maverickosama): `index()` appears to be much more elegant that `prevAll()`!